# How to add tooltip to Ant Design Menu after 4.20.0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

From Ant Design [docs](https://ant.design/components/menu):

> After version 4.20.0, we provide a simpler usage <Menu items={[...]}
> /> with better performance and potential of writing simpler code style
> in your applications. Meanwhile, we deprecated the old usage in
> browser console, we will remove it in antd 5.0.

I would like to show a tooltip when hovering an item in the menu:

```
<Menu
    items={[
        { key: 'key1', label: 'Option 1' },
        { key: 'key2', label: 'Option 2', disabled: isDisabled }, // Show tooltip on hover when disabled
    ]}
    onClick={handleMenuClick}
/>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the [ItemType docs](https://ant.design/components/menu#itemtype), you'll see that `label` is a **ReactNode** type. Add your tooltip there:

```
<Menu
  onClick={onClick}
  selectedKeys={[current]}
  mode="horizontal"
  items={[
    {
      label: <Tooltip title="menu one">Menu One</Tooltip>,
      key: "one"
    },
    {
      label: <Tooltip title="menu two">Menu Two</Tooltip>,
      key: "two"
    },
    {
      label: <Tooltip title="menu three">Menu Three</Tooltip>,
      key: "three"
    }
  ]}
/>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/top-navigation-antd-5-0-4-forked-9rkdb8?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Only when hovering the label, the tooltip would become visible. Not ideal.

Comment: Why isn't it ideal? The label is what shows in the menu and if you need to add an icon, add the icon as part of the label.

Comment: The tooltip won't show until you hover over the label. For example, if I want to show a tooltip that shows a message about why the menu item is disabled - would be ideal if as soon as the mouse enters the item, the tooltip is shown. The label does not fill the entire item.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Unfortunately with the API in the newer version, adding to the `label` is the best option.